# How to add a tab menu item in a module?

Tags: php, xml, joomla

I have try to add new Tab menu item in module menu in mod-*******.xml . But it doesn't work. How can I add like this tab menu in the module?

[image: like this]

Answer (score 1):

**open your module xml file find the `</fieldset>` after create as own example below:**

```
<fieldset name="custom" label="tab name">
            <field
                   name="lang"
                   type="sql"
                   default="1"
                   label="Select a language"
                   query="SELECT id AS value, lang FROM #__helloworld" />
        </fieldset>
```

refer https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types